# Apache Pig Group / Flatten / Join

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

I have 2 datasets.

Set A has a number of events, each occurring on a date, with multiple events per date.  Eg:

```
10/23/2015, event1
10/23/2015, event2
9/17/2014, event3
```

Set B has a weather observation for each date.  There is only one observation per date.  Eg:

```
10/23/2015, obs1
10/22/2015, obs2
9/17/2014, obs3
```

I would like to attached to each event the weather observation for its respective date, Eg:

```
10/23/2015, event1, obs1
10/23/2015, event2, obs1
9/17/2014, event3, obs3
```

I think this can be accomplished by grouping set A by date, doing an inner join with set B by date, and then flattening the result.

Would somebody please let me know if that is the best way, and show me the code to use?  Thanks

Comment: Are these records one-per-line or is a single record 3 tuples? Or what code do you have so far to load these datasets?

Comment: One per line, sorry for the confusion.

I basically want to do in Pig what you would call a vlookup in excel: take an event from Set A, look up its date in set B, and pull the observation from set B.

Answer (score 0):

No grouping and flattening needed. Just a join, then you have to remove the duplicated `date` column.

```
a = LOAD 'datasetA.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (date:chararray, evt:chararray);
b = LOAD 'datasetB.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (date:chararray, obs:chararray);
c_join = a JOIN b ON a.date == b.date;
c = FOREACH c_join GENERATE a::date, a::evt, b::obs;
```

Output

```
dump c;
(9/17/2014, event3, obs3)
(10/23/2015, event2, obs1)
(10/23/2015, event1, obs1)
```